# Why is IIS 7.5 showing two requests for static files?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, static-content, static-files

We are running IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit.  Mainly, we run Coldfusion 9 and don't really use ASP.NET stuff.

Kind of weird, but when we look at the "Worker Processes" module (on the main server entry in the "IIS" group) and view the current requests for a worker, it always shows double entries for static files.  Images, icons (for favicons), and even extensionless URLs always have double entries.  However, entries for our Coldfusion files do not do this.  I've linked to a screenshot below to show what I mean (the first column is the IIS site ID and the second is the URL).

[image: IIS double request entries (posted as link since I cannot add an image yet...)]

Is there any reason for this?  Is the server actually processing requests for static files twice?

I played with our app pool settings and set all of our app pools to "No Managed Code" (since our Coldfusion sites never touch ASP.NET) and to the "Classic" pipeline mode, however, it did not help this issue (from what I read up on the "Integrated" pipeline mode, I figured this may have been why).

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason, just don't know how to solve it.
The reason is that you probably have added a Handler Mapping in IIS 7.5.

Probably you have a Wildcard Script Map with request path: * pointing to: jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll

If you remove that Mapping, static content is not shown twice in the request list.
Problem is: you need this Wildcard mapping to have CF work correct with IIS 7.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

COuld be any of a number of reasons. First, you look at it from the wrong side. It is not IIS showing two requests, it is the browser ASKING FOR THE FILE TWICE. IIS reports what it serves, the requests do not originate there.

Is Templates open to an unauthorized user? Could be the first request is answered with "Authorization needed"?

Show us the complete log file (with the resulting status and transferred bytes) and we can likely help.